# How to implement dynamic 301 redirects for 40,000 pages built in PHP?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

I want to change my site URLs into meaningful ones, but many of them have back links from other sites. Will changing URLs will affect my back links or my indexing?

What is the best way to do this redirection, given that the site is huge (+40,000 pages?)  The old site is built with pure PHP as well as the CMS built in house using MySQL database. We are building a new website in pure PHP and the CMS in Laravel.

Both websites follow the same structure.

Comment: Here is a very similar question that has a lot more detail.  Some of the answers may help you: [Moving large website to new CMS - URL changes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/moving-large-website-to-new-cms-url-changes)

Comment: Really, the people building your CMS should be answering this, and if they can't, they are not qualified to rebuild the site.   You can use your web server (you did not specify if you are using Apache, NGINX or something else).    You can also use the PHP *header("Location: xxx", true, 301)* to handle redirects.   Changing URL's will affect  your indexing and backlinks, but done intelligently, not significantly.